# My app keeps stopping; Why can't I run my app?

Tags: java, android

My app keeps stopping when I open the emulator. I tried putting in a different application; only the first screen and class and it still stopped.

it shows the following trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dearpet, PID: 31496
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dearpet/com.example.dearpet.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.dearpet.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2839)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.dearpet.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2829)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Please add the code that you are running, so that others can help you debug it.

Comment: Post the code for your `MainActivity`. My hunch is that you've either declared the class `abstract`, or you're attempting to invoke your `MainActivity` via its constructor.

Comment: InstantiationException is thrown : if this Class represents an abstract class, an interface, an array class, a primitive type, or void; or if the class has no nullary constructor; or if the instantiation fails for some other reason. You need to share your code if you want help. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()

Answer (score -1):

try to start your app without any code , and add just one line every time until the error back

היי ים, תנסי להפעיל את האפליקציה שלך עם הקוד הבסיסי ביותר ( או בלי קוד בכלל אם זה חוקי ) ותוסיפי כל פעם שורה אחת עד שהשגיאה תחזור